# Настройка статического IP для облачной службы Azure

Tags: azure, ip

Здравствуйте!

Возникла проблема. IP адрес данный по умолчанию в облачной службе Azure динамический. То есть при остановке службы он меняется. Необходимо сделать статический.

Перелопатили кучу материалов (в том числе и оф. мануал)
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

Но, может быть, в виду чего-либо не до конца поняли, как исправить. В том числе не поняли, где и как редактировать конфигурационный файл облака

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="ReservedIPSample" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <Role name="WebRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
       <ReservedIP name="MyWebSiteIP"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Соответственно вопрос: подскажите, как настроить статический IP для облачной службы с учетом того, что основная машина облачной службы UbuntuServer.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А Azure SDK установлен? 
Я вот только что-то не понял... Ты пытаешься Web-Role сконфигурировать или виртуальную машину? Роли не могут быть, вроде как, на убунте, они на Win2012 все работают. 
Этот файл действителен только для Cloud Services. То бишь для Web или Worker Roles и конфигурируется из Deployment-проекта. А если у тебя просто виртуалка в Azure крутится, то там всё через PowerShell сконфигурировать нужно (ну или через REST API).

Comment: Такое ощущение, что ты путаешь Cloud Services и Infrastruсеure Services. Простая виртуалка это Infrastructure Services. А если у тебя просто виртуалка в Azure крутится, то там всё через PowerShell сконфигурировать нужно, без этой XMLки (ну или через REST API).

Comment: Возможно, и путаю. У меня простая задача, чтобы на моем DNS имени, которое привязано к CloudService, IP был статический. Сейчас он динамический...

Comment: Так в итоге это просто виртуалка или всё таки Web/Worker Role? От этого есть разница как конфигурировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что у тебя всё-таки просто виртуальная машина в Azure, а не роль. Поэтому для конфигурации придется попариться в PowerShell. Если вкратце, то примерно так:

1. Резеврируешь IP. Для этого открываешь Azure PowerShell, туда вписываешь: `New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName “MyWebsiteIP” –Label “WebsiteIP” –Location “Japan West”` (Параметры в кавычках можешь, само собой, изменить).

**UPDATE 18.10.2017: на сегодняшний день лучше использовать новый cmdlet - New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress**

2. Необходимо создать НОВУЮ виртуалку с зарезервироанным IP. Прикрутить к старой нельзя. Никак. Совсем. Да, я пробовал. Максимум можешь использовать старый VHD (виртуальный жесткий диск с твоей убунтой), но как бы сама виртуалка всё равно должна быть новой. Создавать при этом тоже надо через Azure PowerShell. Через портал не работает пока что.
   [Тут вот есть инструкция](http://michaelwasham.com/2013/01/11/how-to-provision-a-linux-vm-in-a-vnet-with-powershell/) о том, как создать виртуалку с Linux из PowerShell. При этом надо к команде New-AzureVM добавить параметр `-ReservedIPName "MyWebSiteIP"`.

**UPDATE 18.10.2017: это стало вроде бы возможным**

Ну вот, в общем-то, и всё. Но создать виртуалку со старым диском может быть несколько проблематичным, если нет опыта работы с Azure PowerShell. Если нет опыта в этом, то, может быть, будет даже быстрее просто по-новой всё установить.

Comment: 2 виртуальные машины подключены к облачной службе через группу масштабирования. На этой панели на русском языке написано облачная служба. У нее есть выданное dns имя. xxxx.cloudapp.net и есть Общедоступный виртуальный IP-адрес. Но этот VIP меняется при выключении машины, он ДИНАМИЧЕСКИЙ. Моя задача сделать статическим.

Comment: Тогда то, что я написал выше, подходит под этот случай. Тебе нужен Reserved IP. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690120.aspx Если есть конкретные вопросы, то могу попытаться ответить, но целиком весь процесс по шагам описывать это очень много.

Comment: ок. Буду пробовать.